# Find the NDK version used for building OpenCV Android native libraries

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android

Suppose I have prebuilt OpenCV Android native libraries, such as [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/tag/3.4.3). How to find which version of NDK is used for building this?

I am curios about this because OpenCV 3.4.3 prebuilt Android libraries seems to incompatible (?) with NDK r18.

Comment: I don't think you can infer the NDK version used just by reading the libraries. But you can check its other documentations to see if this information is documented. E.g. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Android_Release_Notes

Comment: also here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/cmake/android, it looks no specified NDK version ...

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV library contained this information. Open the prebuilt library in Notepad++ and search for "General configuration for OpenCV".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it was built with a new enough version of the NDK (I don't remember exactly when we added this, but it's been a year or two), there's an ELF note baked into the binaries. Can use https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/parse_elfnote.py to parse it. It'll show you something like the following:

```
$ python parse_elfnote.py $NDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so
----------ABI INFO----------
ABI_ANDROID_API: 21
ABI_NDK_VERSION: r18
ABI_NDK_BUILD_NUMBER: 5002713
```